# Como utilizar css en input de manera correcta

Tags: css

Se supone que los inputs deben estar transparentes y me salen de esta manera... Alguien sabe como lograr que se vean bien[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so], te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y, de paso, ganar tu primera medalla. También es importante que leas [ask] y [mcve] para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, de esta manera favoreces a que los usuarios las respondan y te ayuden. ¿Qué has probado? ¿Por qué no ha funcionado? ¿Da algún error? Si dejas más datos favoreces a que te ayuden y no a que te hagan la tarea :)

Comment: Se supone que tienen que estar transparente, pero nosotros no sabemos por que se supone eso. Con tu código **HTML** y **CSS** podríamos ver que es lo que está ocurriendo.

Answer (score 3):

Puedes agregar una clase a los inputs con estos estilos.

```
.your-class{
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance:    none;
   appearance: none;
   background-color: transparent;
}
```

Con esos estilos de css, lo que haces es quitar los estilos por defecto de los input de la mayoria de los navegadores (https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-appearance) y con la propiedad `background-color` asignas un color transparente al input.

Comment: puedes agregar una regla para que no aparezca el color del borde, asi todo esta uniforme con el fondo como seria: border-color: transparent;